# Bernstein's inequality for normal random variables

Tags: inequality, random-variables

I am a little uncertain with the use of Bernstein's inequality. I know that for a random variable that is always greater than 0, bernstein's inequality gives $P[X>c]\leq e^{-ct}*M_X(t)$, where $M_X(t)$ is the moment generating function of X. However, if X is a normal variable, how can I apply Bernstein? I tried to do the calculation with c=10 and X being standard normal: $P[X>c]\leq e^{-ct}*M_X(t)= P[X>10]\leq e^{-10*10}*e^{10^2/2}=e^{-50}$ which I think is too small.

Comment: If $X\sim N(0,1)$ then it is true that $P(X>10)\leq e^{-50}$. You can verify this by checking here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k1y5j8uchw

Comment: @MatthewHolder Thank you!